# Regex with OR in Java - mongoDB

Tags: java, regex, mongodb

How can I create the following query:

Name LIKE "ABC" or "DFG" in java driver for mongoDB?

I know that for creating regex without "or" I do it in this way:

```
  BasicDBObject regexQuery = new BasicDBObject();
  regexQuery.put("name",
       new BasicDBObject("$regex", "ABC"));
```

Answer (score 3):

The normal | operator works on mongo.

This should do:

```
BasicDBObject regexQuery = new BasicDBObject();
regexQuery.put("name",
       new BasicDBObject("$regex", "ABC\\|DFG"));
```

If trying on mongo shell:

```
db.collection.find({name:/ABC|DFG/}).pretty()
```

Comment: one can also use Pattern.compile("ABC\\|DFG")