# MongoDB query for value in field with regex using Java

Tags: java, mongodb

I am trying to query from my collection of documents which looks like:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("94"), "EmailAddress" :"adam@gmail.com","Interests": "CZ1001,CE2004" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("44"), "EmailAddress" :"ben@gmail.com", "Interests":"CE1001,CE4002" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54"), "EmailAddress" :"chris@gmail.com","Interests":"CE1001,CE2002" }
```

An example is that i want to retrieve the email addresses, given that the field **"Interests"** has that value i am looking for.

Example if i search CZ1001, i will get back Obj 1 EmailAddress details.

If i search CE1001, i will get back Obj 2 and Obj 3 EmailAddress details.

The object id are uniquely created when i inserted records at the start if that helps.

I am able to get the objects on MongoDB Shell using

```
db.users.find(Module: {"$regex": "CE1001"}})
```

Only the email addresses are needed.

I am trying to get all the email addresses and got stuck at this code.

```
Document doc = (Document) collection.find(new BasicDBObject("Module", {"$regex":"CE1001"})) .projection(Projections.fields(Projections.include("EmailAddress"), Projections.excludeId())).first();
```

Where 
`new BasicDBObject("Module", {"$regex":"CE1001"})` is not allowed.

`new BasicDBObject("Module", String_variable)` is allowed

Comment: can't you store `Interests` as an array?

Comment: This a project that is done previously by others, i have no control over how it was stored at start. So i can't do that.

Comment: What do you mean by "in java"? Are you fetching all the documents and want to filter on results? What do you have so far?

Comment: Java as in, i want to retrieve those emails and from there proceed to send notifications alert to those emails. 
I am able to get the objects on MongoDB Shell using db.users.find(Module: {"$regex": "CE1001"}})

Comment: If you are able to get the object on shell, then what's the issue?

Comment: If you use the mongo-java-driver, in `QueryBuilder` there is the `regex` method: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.8/javadoc/index.html?com/mongodb/QueryBuilder.html

Comment: mongodb java does not allow for access of the collection.find in that way.

Document doc = (Document) collection.find(new BasicDBObject("Module", {"$regex":"CE1001"}))                        .projection(Projections.fields(Projections.include("EmailAddress"), Projections.excludeId())).first();

new BasicDBObject("Module", {"$regex":"CE1001"}) is not allowed. 
However 
new BasicDBObject("Module", String_variable) is allowed

Comment: Try `new BasicDBObject("Module", new BasicDBObject("$regex", "CE1001")) `

Comment: Try `doc.getString("EmailAddress")`

Comment: @Veeram Thank you! Just found that out too. However i could only get 1 record, as i am using the .first() at the end of the collection find.

Is there a way to repeat like a for loop to check the whole records to see if there are any more records that fits the "CE1001"?

If i remove .first() though, there will be an error stated.

Comment: Try `FindIterable<Document> results= collection.find..
for(Document doc : results) { ...
}`

Comment: @Veeram 
FindIterable<Document> results =  collection.find(new BasicDBObject("Module", new BasicDBObject("$regex","CE1001"))).projection(Projections.fields(Projections.include("EmailAddress"), Projections.excludeId())).first();  
Gives an error on "Document cannot be converted to  FindIterable<Document>.

So i tried 
 FindIterable<Document> results =  (FindIterable<Document>) collection.find
but when compiled i get the following error 
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.bson.Document cannot be cast to com.mongodb.client.FindIterable"

Comment: You want all ? don't use first

Comment: @Veeram
Wow so that was why it didnt work!! Thank you for the help!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex with OR in Java - mongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48078273/regex-with-or-in-java-mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

For a particular `Interest`, your mongoDB query would look like(taking CE1001 as an example):

```
db.collection.find({
  $or: [
    {
      Interests: {
        $regex: "^CE1001,"
      }
    },
    {
      Interests: {
        $regex: ",CE1001,"
      }
    },
    {
      Interests: {
        $regex: ",CE1001$"
      }
    }
  ]
},
{
  "EmailAddress": 1
})
```

Answer (score 0):

For others who happens to drop by this post. Below are the working codes. Credits to @Veeram.

```
FindIterable <Document> results = collection.find(new BasicDBObject("Module", new BasicDBObject("$regex", "CE1001")) .projection(Projections.fields(Projections.include("EmailAddress"), Projections.excludeId()));

for(Document doc : results) {
doc.getString("EmailAddress")
 }
```